# Is it equivalent between ImmutableMap and unmodifiableMap with HashMap / LinkedHashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap, guava, linkedhashmap

Is it equivalent between

```
return ImutableMap.copyOf(map);
```

and

```
return Collections.unmodifiableMap(new HashMap(map));
return Collections.unmodifiableMap(new LinkedHashMap(map));
```

And is second way thread-safe?

(ImutableMap from Guava, I try second way because ImmutableMap doesn't support null-value)

Comment: They are functionally equivalent, and both are thread-safe.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov it seems that question doen't consider thread problem

Answer (score 2):

The only difference b/w the two is an unmodified map will get updated if the map it is backing is updated.

While an immutable map is truly immutable.

You create an unmodified map, which will behave similar to Immutable map.

```
Map<String, String> immutableMap = 
Collections.unmodifiableMap(new HashMap<String, String>(map));
```

Both are thread safe in sense as you are restricting update.